# How to get a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have this code

```
<?php
setcookie('page', 'settings', time(),'/');
header('Location: settings.php');
?>
```

but every time I check the cookie with $_COOKIE['page'] is empty?

Comment: Using time() tells it to expire when you set it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cookie always expires, use:

```
setcookie('page', 'settings', time()+3600,'/'); // + 1 hour
```

also add a an exit for your script in case you have something bellow header:

```
<?php
    setcookie('page', 'settings', time()+3600, '/');
    header('Location: settings.php');
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookie you are sending expires at the moment you send it.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```